# Vue Testing (Jest): cannot find button

Tags: typescript, ts-jest

I have a simple test:

```
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import sinon from "sinon";
import HelloWorld from "../../../../src/DSS/web_resources/CreateSubprocessForm/HelloWorld.vue";

test("Click on yes button calls our method with argument yes", async () => {
    const spy = sinon.spy();
    const wrapper = mount(HelloWorld, {
        propsData: {
            callMe: spy,
        },
        methods: {},
    });

    const button = wrapper.find("button");
    await button.trigger("click");
    expect(spy.calledWith("yes"));
});
```

Vue file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Hello, {{ name }}</div>
    <button class="yes" @click="callYes">Yes</button>
    <button class="no" @click="callNo">No</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    callMe: {
      type: Function
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "",
      count: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
      callYes() {
        this.callMe('yes')
      },
      callNo() {
        this.callMe('no')
      }
    }
});
</script>
```

wrapper.find("button") did not find the button. I also tried with findAll...result length is  0... also i tried with wrapper.find("button.yes")

vue/test-utils: 1.3.0,
jest: 26.6.3

Any idea what I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

can you check what is coming inside wrapper.html() ?
Also if you provide reproduction repo that would be helpful to help you.